# Is majority vote prediction effective when undersampling with the random forest algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

Ok I know that my question is weird (I am new to machine learning), I'll try to be more specific. I have a dataset with 7 classes with respective frequencies: 211.840, 283.301, 35.754, 2.747, 9.493, 17.367 and 20.510. Since the classes are imbalanced, my idea is to create many different under-sampled datasets, then train a random forest classifier on each dataset and finally get my final predictions from the majority vote of all these classifiers. Is my thought valid? Am I ignoring any important point?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try SMOTE or some other techniques to deal with class imbalance problems.

Read about Random forests:
https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm

Random Forests actually grows many trees by taking subsamples and classifies by taking votes of those trees.
You need not do that again seperately.

Try ensembles with different classifiers instead.
Or try some other boosting techniques like ADABOOST algorithm.